# PerformanceCounterCategory.Create breaks with The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, wcf, performancecounter

So I'm creating a couple custom performance counters and grouping them under a single category.  This is built inside a WCF application hosted on IIS 7 and running through visual studio.

I've been following msdn's example and documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb32hxtc.aspx)

Here's the code that I'm using in my method:

```
if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("MyCategory"))
{
    PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete("MyCategory");
}

CounterCreationDataCollection counters = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
CounterCreationData getRequests = new CounterCreationData();
getRequests.CounterName = "Get count per sec";
getRequests.CounterHelp = "Get count per sec";
getRequests.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.RateOfCountsPerSecond64;
counters.Add(getRequests);

CounterCreationData headRequests = new CounterCreationData();
headRequests.CounterName = "Head count per sec";
headRequests.CounterHelp = "Head count per sec";
headRequests.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.RateOfCountsPerSecond64;
counters.Add(headRequests);

PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("MyCategory", "Custom Category", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance,counters);
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the last line is giving me an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The parameter is incorrect

EDIT:

The call stack looks like the following:

> System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.RegisterFiles(String
>   arg0, Boolean unregister)
>   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.RegisterCategory(String
>   categoryName, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, String
>   categoryHelp, CounterCreationDataCollection creationData)
>   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(String
>   categoryName, String categoryHelp, PerformanceCounterCategoryType
>   categoryType, CounterCreationDataCollection counterData)

I was wondering if anyone knows or have seen this issue?

Comment: Do you have admin rights - I think you need them to create category

Comment: :( I don't have admin rights. You'd think the exception handler would return an UnauthorizedAccessException as opposed to something weird like "The parameter is incorrect"...

Comment: dont know, sorry. try this on pc you are admin on, to check.

Comment: probably yes, it will. Can you update your post with Win32Exception details?

Comment: What kind of additional details are you referring to? I've gone ahead and attached the callstack to the post, but all the output window gave was what I have already listed above.